# Downloading music tracks

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I have tried to download (sync) music tracks from Win10 to Android & it seems to go OK but I cannot find it anywhere on my Phone (marshmallow).Where do I look please

Comment: Depends on how you "downloaded/sync'd" them. Could you please [edit] your question and add those details? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

find / -iname *.mp3

or esfileexplorer and the like have a show by type feature.